# Optional parameter on laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a route like this. I want the first parameter will be an optional parameter. For example: students/service/123/detail & service/123/detail. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

```
Route::get('{optionalParam}/{slug}/{registrationCode}/detail', [SubmissionController::class, 'submissionDetail'])->name('submission.detail');
```

Comment: declare two routes

Comment: Duplicate: see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908836/laravel-5-routing-to-controller-with-optional-parameters

Comment: The documentation has a section on [Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), see if that helps.

Comment: You can make a route parameter optional by using `{optionalParam?}` as you can find in the documentation, but since your first parameter is the one that needs to be optional, I would define a separate route for it.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), optionals parameters are in the last position.

The reason is simple. For example this route :

```
Route::get('{param1?}/{param2}/{param3}
```

If you pass nothing as `param1`, then `param2` will become `param1`. So I advice you to use the same route, with a required parameter like this :

```
Route::get('{optionalParam}/{slug}/{registrationCode}/detail', [SubmissionController::class, 'submissionDetail'])->name('submission.detail');
```

And after in your controller, check if this parameter is the default you defined or not. For example, you can define a default value, like `0` and this value will indicate you that this parameter doesn't exist :

```
public function test($optionalParam, $slug, $registrationCode)
{
    if ($optionalParam === 0) {
        // here the parameter doesn't exist
    }

    // here the parameter exists
}
```