# laravel dynamic routing showing 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a route to pass dynamic parameters to controller but when i serve url it shows me for not found here is my route and controller I create

Routes

```
Route::get('/admin/managers/{method}/{id}', 
    [
        SetupController::class, 'managers'
    ]
);
```

Controller

```
public function managers($method, $id) {
        if($method == 'create') {
            return view('admin.pages.create-manager'); 
        } elseif($method == 'create') {
            echo $id;
            return view('admin.pages.create-manager'); 
        } else {
            return view('admin.pages.managers'); 
        }  
    }
```

When i serve url localhost/public/managers it shows me 404 not found but when i serve localhost/public/managers/create/1 the page is loading then can anyone hep me out why exactly is it happening

Comment: have you run `php artisan optimize` after creating?

Comment: I just ran this given command after thenat I ran the url http://localhost/micamp/public/admin/managers it shows 404 not found nd when i run this url http://localhost/micamp/public/admin/managers/create/1 it loads the page

Comment: some times when creating new route laravel won't it so you have to run `php artisan optimize` and it will work

Comment: the reason that it not found  `localhost/micamp/public/admin/managers` is because your route needs 2 parameters and you are not giving any parameter

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to achieve I need all 3 circumstances to be done as managers to show all managers managers/create when creating a new manager managers/create/1 when editing the manager

Comment: in that case make your parameters `{method}` and `{id}` as an optional parameter like this`{method?}/${id?}`

Comment: and change your controller like this `public function managers($method=null, $id=null)`

Comment: and also please see this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908836/routing-to-controller-with-optional-parameters#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20way%20to%20call%20a%20controller%20from%20a%20Route%3A%3A%3Aget%20closure.

Comment: Route::get('/admin/managers/{method?}/${id?}', [SetupController::class, 'managers']);

and in controller public function managers($method = null, $id = null) now all 3 links re showing 404 not found am I doing something wrong

Comment: run `php artisan optimize`

Comment: sure i will do it now

Comment: `{method?}/{id?}` Using multiple optional parameters is a bad idea... If you have a URL like `admin/managers/1`, is `1` supposed to be `$method` or `$id`? _We_ know it should be `$id`, but the code is not smart enough to determine that. I'd recommend using a proper Query String `/admin/managers?id=1` and `$request->input('id')`, since you can omit/reference query strings as key/value pairs, not arbitrary placement in a URL. (moved here since there are multiple answers suggesting this; avoid if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as we discussed in the comments what you need is to make your parameters optional like below

change your route like this

```
    Route::get('/admin/managers/{method?}/{id?}', [SetupController::class, 'managers']);
```

and your controller like this

```
public function managers($method=null, $id=null) {
    if ($method == 'create') {
        return view('admin.pages.create-manager'); 
    } elseif ($method == 'edit') { // change here
        echo $id;
        return view('admin.pages.create-manager'); 
    } else {
        return view('admin.pages.managers'); 
    }  
}
```

and also don't forget to run at the end

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your code, the second if condition is checking for the same value 'create', this resulting in a 404 error for the URL "localhost/public/managers".

To resolve this issue, change the second if condition to check for another value. For example, if you want to show the page with the id, use the following code:

```
public function managers($method, $id) {
if ($method == 'create') {
    return view('admin.pages.create-manager'); 
} elseif ($method == 'show') {//or anything else
    echo $id;
    return view('admin.pages.create-manager'); 
} else {
    return view('admin.pages.managers'); 
}
```

}